# creating new classes in a loop according to user input

Tags: python, class, object, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So I'm trying to make a prime sieve that will make a class object that stores the prime number up to a number the user gives.  But I want to run in a loop where the user can keep creating new objects with lists of prime numbers stored, and give them the option to keep doing that.

If they input the same number twice, I want to just print the previous results which have been stored inside the object created from before, instead of replacing the previous object and running through the computing of setting up a whole new list.

1. I think the only thing I'm hung up on is how do I just keep creating new class objects over and over and give the objects new names every time instead of what I did the first time, storing the object in the variable 'c'.

If you look at my code, the sieve will work properly, I just don't know how to make an object without storing it in the variable 'c'

```
history={}
class Eratosthenes(object):

    def __init__(self,b):
        self.limitn=int(b)+1
        self.not_prime = [False]*self.limitn
        self.primes = []

    def do_primes_sieve(self):
        for i in range(2, self.limitn):
            if self.not_prime[i]:
                continue
            for f in xrange(i**2, self.limitn, i):
                self.not_prime[f] = True
            self.primes.append(i)

    def get_primes_til(self):
        for i in self.primes:
            print (i)
    def get_num_of_primes(self):
        print (len(self.primes))

a = True
while a:
    b = raw_input("How far are you going to search?: ")
    if b in history.keys():
        c = history[b]
        c.get_num_of_primes
    else:
        c = Eratosthenes(b)
        history[b] = c
        c.do_primes_sieve()
        c.get_primes_til()
    d = raw_input("Continue? (type 'yes' or 'no'): ")
    if d == "yes":
        continue
    elif d == "no":
        a=False
    else:
        print "This is a 'yes' or 'no' question. We're done here."
        a=False
```

Comment: A class object?

Comment: yes a class object

Comment: Do you care about the *old* instance?  What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: My goal is to create a new instance so that I can have instances in place that the user can call back on if they want to by merely typing their number again.

Comment: Add the instances as key/value pairs to a dictionary -  ```number:instance```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare some class variable (aka static variable), e.g. a dictionary called `history`, which will store results:

```
class Eratosthenes(object):

    history = {}

    def __init__(self,b):
        self.limitn=int(b)+1
        self.not_prime = [False]*self.limitn
        self.primes = []

    def do_primes_sieve(self):
        if self.limitn-1 in Eratosthenes.history.keys():
            self.primes = Eratosthenes.history[self.limitn-1]
        else:
            for i in range(2, self.limitn):
                if self.not_prime[i]:
                    continue
                for f in xrange(i**2, self.limitn, i):
                    self.not_prime[f] = True
                self.primes.append(i)
            Eratosthenes.history[self.limitn-1] = self.primes
```

Then, you could modify your `do_primes_sieve` method so that, if a previous answer exists in the `history` dictionary, the `primes` for the current instance of `Eratosthenes` will be fetched from the dictionary.

Per discussion below, an updated answer that treats `history` as a global:

```
history = {}

class Eratosthenes(object):


    def __init__(self,b):
        self.limitn=int(b)+1
        self.not_prime = [False]*self.limitn
        self.primes = []

    def do_primes_sieve(self):
        for i in range(2, self.limitn):
            if self.not_prime[i]:
                continue
            for f in range(i**2, self.limitn, i):
                self.not_prime[f] = True
            self.primes.append(i)

    def get_primes_til(self):
        for i in self.primes:
            print i 
    def get_num_of_primes(self):
        print len(self.primes)
a = True
while a:
    b = raw_input("How far are you going to search?: ")
    if b in history.keys():
        c = history[b]
        c.get_num_of_primes()
    else:
        c = Eratosthenes(b)
        history[b] = c
        c.do_primes_sieve()
        c.get_primes_til()
    d = raw_input("Continue? (type 'yes' or 'no'): ")
    if d == "yes":
        continue
    elif d == "no":
        a=False
    else:
        print "This is a 'yes' or 'no' question. We're done here."
        a=False
```

Comment: I'm not really hung up on that as much as I am on figuring out how to get the program to make new class instances with new variables to call these with.  For instance, the second time I run through my while loop, it will store the new request instance in 'c' variable instead of something new, and will thus delete the old instance.

Comment: In that case you could have `history` be a global object (move it outside of the class, e.g. to the top of the program). Then, you could store the numbers as keys and the objects as values. E.g., after the line `c = Eratosthenes(b)`, you could add a new line `history[b] = c`. You would also need a conditional in your `while` loop that checks if `b` is in `history.keys()` and, if so, fetch the instance from the `history` dictionary rather than create a new instance.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea. I'll take some time to set that up. I'm new to designing programs so it takes me a while.

Comment: If you're running into any trouble, please feel free to refer to my updated answer, which includes (in the 2nd code block) an implementation treating `history` as a global. One additional piece of advice for program design: I recommend naming non-trivial variables with descriptive names, such as `program_running` rather than `a` and `user_input` rather than `b`.

Comment: so what do i type if i want to call a method to be run on a particular instance then?

Comment: Yes, that would in fact be correct. `do_primes_sieve` is an instance method, and so is bound to whatever instance it is called upon. The program is now designed such that, for each unique user input `b`, there will also be a unique `Eratosthenes` instance associated with that input. If the input hasn't been entered before, `c` will represent a brand new instance; if it has been entered, `c` will represent an instance stored in, and fetched from, the `history` dictionary.

Comment: So i updated it per your recommendations, and I want to just print the amount of prime numbers to an existing instance if it were called. But for some reason it just prints nothing, and moves on.

Comment: I updated my second code block so that, if an existing instance had already been called, it will just print the amount of prime numbers in that instance by calling `get_num_of_primes` on the instance. Otherwise, the program will execute as normal.

Comment: when i copy paste your code it just says "name 'yes' is not defined" when i get to the part where it asks if you want to continue.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote and executed my code against Python3. You are likely using Python2, so I've updated my code to run against Python2.

Comment: I had to change the input into raw_input. Not sure why. But you have solved all of my difficulties and for that sir I thank you.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize Spyder was trying to run it in 2.7 until now.  Not sure how to get it to run in 3.6

Comment: Glad to help! The issue is how Python3 treats the `input()` function versus how Python2 treats the `input()` function. If I've answered your question, please feel free to mark my answer as accepted by toggling the gray check mark beside my answer.